# How can i make ngxLoading a reusable component?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-loading

`enter code here`Hi all I have implemented  ngxLoading on login page it works fine but i need to use it on other pages too, how can i implement it as a reusable component? Thanks for your help.

```html
 <!-- ngx loading -->
              <div class="form-group">
                <ng-template #customLoadingTemplate>
                  <div class="custom-class">
                    <h5 class="text-center">Loading..</h5>
                  </div>
                </ng-template>

                <ngx-loading
                  [show]="loading"
                  [config]="{ backdropBorderRadius: '20px' }"
                  [template]="customLoadingTemplate"
                ></ngx-loading>
              </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F2mm.jpg)

Comment: Seems to be reusable already ... Please provide more context

Comment: It actually works with the ts file, so if i need to use this loader on the other page i will have to copy html and ts code to make it work

Comment: Well no, you have the ngx-loading component already ...

Comment: I do not want copy and paste the same code everywhere I just want to call the component on every page where I want to use it. I hope you get me.